# Serilog console theme in Azure Functions v4

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-functions, serilog

I am using Azure functions v4 with `.NET8.0` and Serilog with the following packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="5.0.1" />
```

and currently my output in console looks like this:
[image]

I am setting up logging in `Program.cs` like this

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
        TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(),
        TelemetryConverter.Events,
        LogEventLevel.Information)
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console(theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Literate)
    .CreateLogger();

services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog(logger, true));
```

and utilize it with `ILogger` in the Azure function endpoint.
From `ASP.NET core` I am used to console colors like this, where each data type is colored differently, like `string`, `int`, `DateTime`, etc:
[image]

How can I get Serilog Console colors like in the second image?
Setting `theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Literate` in setup does not seem to be sufficient.

Additional: Since I get the timestamp from Serilog ine ach log, how can I remove the long gray timestamp like in the first image.

Comment: Where you can see the output in colors?from where you got the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [**Github Comment**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/125#issuecomment-569142684) on the same query as yours, Its not possible to change the colour of Default logging that comes with Azure Function Runtime. Also when you **Trigger** your **Functions**  in your **Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code,** The Functions are triggered via Azure Function Core tools command line, Thus it takes the default logging set in the Azure Function SDK in the backend.

I tried implementing Serilog and using Colorful.Console package to change the output of the response, But it is not read by the Function trigger command line terminal.

With **Colorful.Console**:-

***My Function1.cs code:-***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;
using Console = Colorful.Console;
using Colorful;
using System.Drawing;

public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        ColorfulConsoleLog("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
    }

    private void ColorfulConsoleLog(string message)
    {
        var styleSheet = new StyleSheet(Color.AntiqueWhite);
        Console.WriteLineStyled(message, styleSheet);
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

With ***Serilog:-***

***My Function1.cs code:-***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Formatting.Compact;
using System.Net;

public class Function1
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <sgr color=\"1\">{Properties:j}</sgr>{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();

        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Azure CLI colours set  by default in the code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/dev/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Common/OutputTheme.cs) I also tried the suggestions in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2069) but the Function Core Tools Output logs colour were default even when I changed the Console color in the code:-

**My Function1.cs:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using static Colors.Net.StringStaticMethods;
using System.Net;
using System.Drawing;
using Colors.Net; // Import the required namespace

namespace FunctionApp82
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            ConsoleColor yellow = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            var logMessage = "C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.";
            _logger.LogInformation((logMessage));
            Colors.Net.ColoredConsole.WriteLine(logMessage);
            Colorful.Console.WriteLine(logMessage, Color.DarkGreen);
            ColoredConsole.WriteLine(White(logMessage + "\n"));
            Colorful.Console.WriteLine(logMessage, true);
         

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]